# Fedora 37 takes several minutes to "warm up" after logging in or resuming

Tags: fedora, cinnamon, mate-desktop

I foolishly posted a related question on stackoverflow and was chastised for not asking a programming question. I hope this is the right place. I'm running Fedora 37. I prefer cinnamon but am currently using mate, as I will explain.

After the upgrade to 37 from 36 I noticed that every time the machine resumes from suspend, the desktop icons would not respond to either a double-click or a right-click. After attempting a right-click, 20-30 seconds will pass, then a message will appear about unresponsive app offering force quit. After forcing quit, another 15-30 seconds will pass then the icons will reappear and everything will be fine until the next suspend.

I thought to try other desktops and selected mate. In mate, after the resume the icons respond to mouse clicks and apps will launch but, taking thunderbird as an example, after the window appears the app is totally unresponsive for close to a minute. Then it "wakes up" and works normally.

I have tested the same scenario in fedora 35 and it does not show any slowness or delay.

For reference, this is an i9-10850K using the integrated graphics with 64GB RAM and a samsung ssd. When I boot windows on this machine there is no sign of slowness. Again, for reference, windows is on a separate smasung ssd connected to the same sata controller channel (ports 1&2). I have also tested it with a Radeon graphics card instead of the integrated graphics. That makes no difference.

The most puzzling aspect of this is that I have another machine also running fedora 37 with cinnamon desktop and configured very similarly. It does not exhibit any of these problems. Thing is, its running a Ryzen 5600G, not intel.

If it weren't for the fact that the problem only occurs on the intel box, it would be tempting to conclude that that the unresponsiveness is due to some software processes that are taking an abnormally long time to complete. Perhaps there are some logs that track the activity after login or resume but, if so, I don't know where to look for them.

I am looking for suggestions as to what might be causing this problem and how I might go about investigating it further.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Anything interesting in `dmesg`?

Comment: If you create a new user on the _"laggy"_ computer, is its login/suspend experience similar?

Comment: Nothing usefil in dmesg
Hadn't thought of creating another user.  Good idea,  will try

Comment: I created a new user and then suspended the system. After resuming 2 things happened using cinnamon:
1 - the desktop icons responded to clicks immediately.
2 - after opening a terminal and running a simple command like df or ls -al /mnt, it took a full minute for the commands to produce any output.

So there is slowness all around. Sometimes it's the desktop not responding, other times it's apps launched right after logging it taking 1-5 minutes to respond.

Comment: A had a similar problem with the GPU driver spawning some immortal processes. Did a [workaround](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714477/gpu-seems-to-crash-arch-upon-wake-up) by going to sleep repeatably, then `htop` or `ps - aux | grep` to discover the offender.

Comment: It's very strange that the period of unresponsiveness is long in both cinnamon and mate. It affects both the desktop and apps like thunderbird. It's really not possible to asses whether it's a problem in gnome because it doesn't really have a "desktop".

The most striking observation is that xfce does not exhibit any of these issues. It wakes promptly and both the desktop and apps respond instantly. Also, since I am using the intel cpu graphics, there is no gpu.